# variance/confidence interval of development patterns

Tags: probability, statistics

I was wondering if there is a technique to calculate the variance of developments.

eg. I have paired data eg: 100 110, 200 225, 78 92, 33 20...

This means the developments are: 1.1, 1.125, 1.18, 0.6...

I was wondering if there is a technique to calculate a confidence interval around this. And I was also wondering if there is a way to weight this as well (eg. instead of assuming each development is equal, weigh the 200-225 development twice as much as the 100-110 one.

Comment: Variance confidence intervals are non-trivial. But, [it has an asymptotic distribution you can see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105337/asymptotic-distribution-of-sample-variance-of-non-normal-sample?rq=1), which you could use to estimate one. However, it would be better to use bootstrapping, IMO. As for weightings, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance).

Answer (score 0):

In the situation you describe it seem there is a good chance that
the development scores will be approximately normally distributed.
If you have software available, you can use a standard normality
test (such as Anderson-Darling or Shapiro-Wilk) to see if data are
consistent with sampling from a normal distribution.

For normal data a standard kind of confidence interval for the
population variance is based on the chi-squared distribution.
Let $S^2$ be the sample variance of $n$ normal observations.
Then $Q = (n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1).$ So you
can use printed tables of the chi-squared distribution (or
software) to find values $L$ and $U$ such that
$$P\left(L < Q=\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} < U\right) = 0.95.$$
Then, after some straightforward algebra, a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$
is if the form $$\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U},\, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right).$$
To find a 95% CI for $\sigma,$ take square roots of both endpoints of the
CI for $\sigma^2.$

For example, if $n = 25$ and $S^2 = 0.85$, then a 95% CI is $(0.518, 1.645)$,
where the computation in R statistical software is shown below. [Notice that
$S^2 = 0.85$ lies *within* the interval, but (because the chi-squared distribution is not symmetrical) not at its *center.*]

```
Num = 24*0.85
Num/qchisq(c(.975, .025), 24)
## 0.518239 1.645009
```

Other methods, including boostrap CIs are available if it is clear that
data are not normal. If you need help with a sample of reasonable size,
you can list it in your Question in the format $(1.1, 1.125, 1.18, 0.6, \dots),$
[that is, horizontally, with commas between values], leave me a Comment, and I will take a look.